# Understanding Spring XMLBeanFactory

Tags: java, spring

When I start my project, I get an error in the netbeans IDE

[image: one of the class that I have written]

[image: the main function containing class]

The xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.spring.framework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans  >
    <bean id="newclass" class="springdemo.NewClass.java"/> 
</beans>
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images. It's text so put it in as such. Also always include the error in the question. We cannot just guess what the error is.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I see no error here...

Answer (score 2):

`class="springdemo.NewClass.java"`

".java" is part of the filename, not the class name.

Besides that, I'm not sure why you need a BeanFactory here...

```
NewClass tri = new NewClass();
tri.draw();
```

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the class in your code but rather you should use the framework to get the instance of the required class.

Comment: Reflection is slow, though. I'm sure there's more useful instances where it's needed, but not for this question

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<bean id="newclass" class="springdemo.NewClass"/>
```

instead of

```
<bean id="newclass" class="springdemo.NewClass.java"/>.
```

I think we can not find the class.